# Spring: change i18n file location and resource loading issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to override the i18n file location at runtime using a property that contains its full (absolute) path.

This is what I have:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(@Value("${fileLocation}") String fileLocation) {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("file:" + fileLocation, "classpath:i18n/message");
    return source;
}
```

However the resource isn't loaded.

At `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource::refreshProperties`, there is the following line:

```
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(filename + PROPERTIES_SUFFIX);
```

and resourceLoader is a `XmlWebApplicationContext`.

I've also tried prefixing my absolute file path with `file://`, but it isn't loaded either.

What am I doing wrong ? How to load a file from its absolute path with the XmlWebApplicationContext ?

Note: I've read [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) on how to load resources with Spring but what I get from it is that it should work if I prefix my resource with `file:`, however it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to confirm whether there is a process monitoring your runtime change?

Comment: I reloaded my whole application to make sure it's not a cache problem, if that's what you're asking ?

Comment: Yes, do you get any errors?

Comment: No, I do not, but the file is just not loaded for its i18n, as resource.exists() returns false.

Comment: @Smutje, do you have any idea what the problem could be ?